# Invisible reCaptcha testing

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

I have implemented Google’s invisible reCaptcha on a website, but it doesn’t seem to work correctly. I am trying to trigger it with DevTools and Googlebot/2.1 but my form will always submit successfully. Before Christmas the form was online with a slighty different code already – since I couldn’t trigger reCaptcha I waited until now, just to see that we got about 50 spam mails from one bot.
Now I’ve adjusted the code but don’t have any idea how to test it, since it won’t give me any errors.

Here’s my code:

```js
//HTML5 validation before submitting
const form = document.getElementById('contact-form');
(function() {
  form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    if (!grecaptcha.getResponse()) {
      event.preventDefault();
      grecaptcha.execute();
    }
  });
  onCompleted = function() {
    form.submit();
  }
})();
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post" action="scripts/mail.php" id="contact-form">
    <input type="text" name="input" placeholder="Some input fields">
    <div id='recaptcha' class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="[my_site_key]" data-callback="onCompleted" data-size="invisible"></div>
    <button type="submit" form="contact-form">Send</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Does anyone have an idea what my problem might be?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What **exactly** is not workoing?

Comment: Looks like you only implemented something in JavaScript on the client side here? Bots probably don’t care about that. You need to validate the CAPTCHA response on the server side.

Comment: I honestly don’t know how debug it because it’s invisible and I don’t get any errors in my console. I tried to trigger it using Googlebot/2.1 agent and incognito mode when submitting my form. This method worked here: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo?invisible=true
But my form still submits. As I got over 50 spam mails my guess is that reCaptcha doesn’t get triggered? But as I said, I don’t know how to test or debug it further…

Comment: @CBroe How would I do that? Seeing the Google docs (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible) I assumed their API will validate that for me and submit my form once the response is "good".

Comment: A CAPTCHA that works client-side only, and only decides do I submit this form or not, is rather pointless to begin with. The idea that any spam bots were even “using your form” in the first place, might already be wrong. All they need to do is send the proper POST requests to your server, there does not even have to be any such thing as a traditional “browser” involved. https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Comment: @CBroe Thanks a lot for pointing me into that direction! I honestly didn’t ever see anything about verifying Google’s response anywhere and had a wrong impression about how it works overall. But at I’ve got the server side validation now and it seems to work, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think (or hope) it’s working fine now.
CBroe pointed missing server side validation out. I haven’t seen this page/topic (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) in Google’s docs and in any thread I read.

I followed this tutorial from "Implementing the backend": https://www.pinnacleinternet.com/installing-invisible-recaptcha/ and my force fail is working now!